# How to use serilog seperate file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serilog, c#-to-vb.net, code-conversion

I'm trying to convert an example from C# to VB.NET separate file by level.

C#:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
        .WriteTo.File(DebugLogFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true))
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information)
        .WriteTo.File(InfoLogFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true))
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
        .WriteTo.File(ErrorLogFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true))
    .CreateLogger();
```

VB:

```vb
Log.Logger = New LoggerConfiguration() _
    .MinimumLevel.Debug() _
    .WriteTo.Logger(New Action(Of LoggerConfiguration)(Function(r) r.Filter.ByIncludingOnly((Function(z) z.Level = LogEventLevel.Debug)))) _
    .WriteTo.File("debug.txt") _
       .WriteTo.Logger(New Action(Of LoggerConfiguration)(Function(r) r.Filter.ByIncludingOnly((Function(z) z.Level = LogEventLevel.Information)))) _
    .WriteTo.File(New CompactJsonFormatter(), "info.txt") _
    .CreateLogger
    Log.Debug("Debug")
    Log.Information("info")
```

Result is Debug and info show both Debug.txt and info.txt

Comment: Or have code simple?

Answer (score 2):

I can solve it by this code.

```
 Log.Logger = New LoggerConfiguration() _
            .MinimumLevel.Debug() _
        .WriteTo.Logger(New Action(Of LoggerConfiguration)(Function(r) r.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Function(z) z.Level = LogEventLevel.Debug).WriteTo.File(New CompactJsonFormatter(), "debug.txt"))) _
           .WriteTo.Logger(New Action(Of LoggerConfiguration)(Function(r) r.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Function(z) z.Level = LogEventLevel.Information).WriteTo.File(New CompactJsonFormatter(), "info.txt"))) _
        .CreateLogger
        Log.Debug("Debug")
        Log.Information("info")
```

Code is not simple and so confuse Anyone can make it to simple.